# Bootstrap Modal Does Not Appear When Bootstrap-Transition.js IS included

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I'm using Thomas McDonals's [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) gem within my rails application and whenever I include bootstrap-transition.js my modal popup no longer appears.  The background fades in, but the actual modal window does not present itself.  It's not even shown in the source code, so it's not simply being hidden.  When I remove the bootstrap-transition.js file, the modal works as it should.

Right now, I'm including all bootstrap.js files, so there is nothing unusual about what I'm doing.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get that modal back?  I need the transitions for a carousel I'm using.

EDIT:  For clarity, I am not adding in the bootstrap js files manually, I am simply including them in my Application's application.js file, as instructed by the bootstrap-sass gem.  But, out of the box, the modal window does not work.

Answer (score 0):

why are you ading the Js files? the gem should bring them in throught the asset pipeline, you should only need to import them in your application.js file for your Js and create a css.scss file for the bootstrap css like this:

boot.css.scss:

```
$navbarBackground: #000;
$navbarText: #fff;
$navbarLinkColor: #888;
$navbarBrandColor: #FFF;

@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear.  When I wrote "including the js files", I meant adding them to application.js.  So, I'm doing what you're describing.  Yet, the modal does not work.